# How can i empty my progressbar after its full

Tags: c#, visual-studio, progress-bar

How can i set my progressBar value to 0 if its full when i click the button it loads so fast i cant see anything

my code is

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int i;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;

            if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
            {
              progressBar1.Value = 0;                    
            }
            Refresh();
        }
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code ? What exactly does it do and what exactly do you expect it to do ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz if i click the button the fill the progress bar it doesnt  fill it and. I want if the i click the button that the progressbar fills and when its filled that it will be empty

Answer (score 0):

Your code does exactly what you require.
You may should add a sleep to see something.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(IWantToClearTheProgressbarBeforeWork == true)
                progressBar1.Value = 0;

            int i;
            progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
            progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

            for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
            {
                progressBar1.Value = i;
                Thread.Sleep(100);    // only for testing. Blocks your thread.
            }

            if(IWantToClearTheProgressbarImediatelyAfterWorkIsDone == true)
                progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }
```

Comment: If i try that my progressbar takes much longer to save even i changed the seconds

Comment: You didn't tell us about some code actually doing work. If you save 100 files you can replace Threat. Sleep()  with file.Save() for each file. Otherwise you can find plenty of examples here at SO shouwing youbhow to properly implement progress.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you mean?

```
private async void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        int i;
        progressBar1.Minimum = 0;
        progressBar1.Maximum = 100;

        for (i = 0; i <= 100; i++)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = i;
        }

        await Task.Delay(2000);
        if (progressBar1.Value == 100)
        {
            progressBar1.Value = 0;
        }

    }
```

- Edit this will now wait 2 seconds until it sets it to empty so you can see that the progress bar does increment to 100.

Comment: I need the progressbar to be empty when the progressbar is fully loaded